# How can I 'lock' the position of an object when applying curve displacement?

Tags: animation, modifiers, bezier-curves

I'm trying to simulate quickly the waving of a flag by deforming it with a curve modifier and moving that modifier along it's local x-axis, giving the impression that it's waving and allowing it to be easily looped. However, moving the curve also shifts the position of the 'fabric' around. Images below:

**Before moving the curve:**

[image: Without moving the curve]

**After moving the curve:**

[image: After moving curve]

So in the second image I would like the flag to remain aligned to the pole, but with a different displacement. How can I resolve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

I recommend using the [Wave Modifier] for various reasons including

- The Wave Modifier is often used for this purpose.  Its purpose is very clear.
- Your curve above may not be long enough for longer repetitive motion and the endpoints tangents could affect the final result.
- The difficulty you are already experiencing
- The Wave Modifier has a [falloff] to keep the flag attached to the pole.  No Pun Intended. The selected empty serves this purpose in the image above.
- As an alternative that you can create a vertex group to limit the vertex movement on the flag mesh near the pole, to zero.
- As a [Not Recommended] alternative you could animate the curve rather than moving it.